# JavaScript + discord.js: How do you use an object's property in another object in both stored in the same object?

Tags: javascript, object, discord.js

So I'm making a bot to host a Discord RPG, and I was making the player data storage. I ran into a problem with some stats that required the playr level stored in another object to calculate it's own value. When I ran the program in PowerShell, the moment I had to use the variable, it returned `TypeError: Cannot read property 'level' of undefined`. How do I fix this?

```
const fs = require('fs');
var userData = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('userData.json', 'utf8'));

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on('message', message => {
    if (!userData[message.author.id]) {
        level: {
            lvl: 0,
            exp: 0,
            lvlupreq: 100
        },
        stats: {
            maxhp: 200 + userData[message.author.id].level.lvl * 5,
            hp: 200,
            atk: 5 + userData[message.author.id].level.lvl,
            def: 5 + userData[message.author.id].level.lvl,
            planet: 1
        },
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You accidentally created [labeled statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) instead of creating an object and adding properties to it.

If `userData[message.author.id]` does not exist, you first need to create it with initial values:

```
if (!userData[message.author.id]) {
    userData[message.author.id] = {
        level: {
            lvl: 0,
            exp: 0,
            lvlupreq: 100,
        },
        stats: {
            maxhp: 200,
            hp: 200,
            atk: 5,
            def: 5,
            planet: 1,
        },
    }
}
```

The stats update might has to be done for all users though, depending on your further logic (not really necessary in your example code):

```
Object.assign(userData[message.author.id].stats, {
    maxhp: 200 + userData[message.author.id].level.lvl * 5,
    atk: 5 + userData[message.author.id].level.lvl,
    def: 5 + userData[message.author.id].level.lvl,
});
```

The use of [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) in this case is equivalent to writing one assignment per property:

```
userData[message.author.id].stats.maxhp = 200 + userData[message.author.id].level.lvl * 5;
userData[message.author.id].stats.atk = 5 + userData[message.author.id].level.lvl;
userData[message.author.id].stats.def = 5 + userData[message.author.id].level.lvl;
```